# Highlight JS not working on Production but working on Development

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Can anyone figure out the solution why is my Highlight JS is not working on the production but it's working perfectly on the production?

I am using Laravel 10, Cloudflare and Litespeed Web Server

Here is my External CDN for Highlight JS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.8.0/build/styles/github-dark.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.8.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/highlightjs-copy/dist/highlightjs-copy.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/highlightjs-copy/dist/highlightjs-copy.min.css" />
```

And here is my script to initialize HighlightJS on **post.blade.php**

```
@push('script')
    <script>
        hljs.addPlugin(new CopyButtonPlugin());
        hljs.highlightAll();
    </script>
@endpush
```

I call it on the **main.blade.php**

@stack('script')

Thanks for helping

Comment: Check your browser console first, does it give you any error or warning ?

Comment: What does not work? please specify

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now guys, it's weird in the Development Server i don't need to use JQuery, but in the Production Server i need to initialize the code with JQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        hljs.addPlugin(new CopyButtonPlugin());
        hljs.highlightAll();
    });
</script>
```